# Carrierwave gem Secure File Path Cannot read file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I tried to follow the 'Secure Upload' in carrier wave which is a bit confusing because I have customized the file path and all a bit. When I try to run the app, I get 'Cannot read file' error.

Here's the route :

```
match "/uploads/tobereviewed/:user.:username.downcase/:basename.:extension", :controller => "photos", :action => "uploaded", via: :get
```

The sotre_dir of uploader :

```
class SubmitUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

def store_dir
  "uploads/tobereviewed/#{model.user.username.downcase}"
end
```

carrierwave.rb initializer :

```
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.permissions = 0600
      config.directory_permissions = 0700
      config.root = Rails.root
    end
```

Photos controller :

```
    def uploaded

        file = Submit.first

        send_file "#{Rails.root}/uploads/tobereviewed/#{file.user.username.downcase}/#{file.id}"
    end
```

The full error log :

```
Started GET "/uploaded" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-27 18:19:09 +0530
Processing by PhotosController#uploaded as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Submit Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "submits".* FROM "submits"  ORDER BY "submits"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Sent file /home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/uploads/tobereviewed/thpubs/36603935 (0.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms

ActionController::MissingFile - Cannot read file /home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/uploads/tobereviewed/thpubs/36603935:
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/data_streaming.rb:68:in `send_file'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:49:in `block in send_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:47:in `send_file'
   () home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:24:in `uploaded'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:780:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:257:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:558:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/application.rb:161:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
   () home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
   () home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
   () home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2014:18:19:09 +0530] "GET /uploaded HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0743
```

Update :

I set the correct file path like this :

```
send_file "#{file.filename.file}"
```

But then it gives this error :

```
Cannot read file #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f570c2b9e58>
```

**Is my routes correct?**

Comment: Do you get the error on development or production?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti In development. Haven't tried in production

Comment: Can you post a little more about the error? Check your production.log for more information.  My guess is you have anerror in setting the filepath.

Comment: @PhilM. Just posted the full error log

Comment: In development, does the file `/home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/uploads/tobereviewed/thpubs/36603935` exist?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to uploads directory, do `ls -l` to check permissions

Comment: I am certainly sure you miss the extension to your file, dont you? @Momer already said this, with no response by yours.

Comment: @PhilM. I finally fixed it but now i think the route.rb is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your setup CarrierWave should save your file inside "/home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/public/uploads/tobereviewed/thpubs/#{model.user.username.downcase}/somefile.ext"

So, ideally your code should be

```
send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/#{file.image.url}"
```

Assuming your upload column is image.

Comment: No it's not going to the public folder. I set the correct file path like this :

    send_file "#{file.filename.file}"

But then it gives this error :

    Cannot read file #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f570c2b9e58>

Answer (score 1):

Setup debugger in the controller's action.

```
def uploaded
  file = Submit.first

  debugger

  send_file "#{file.filename.file}"
end
```

Now, request the action again and go to the debugger console. A tip here is to open "irb" inside the debugger. Just type "irb" and hit enter.

See what file.filename.file is returning. I believe it's an invalid path, so check if the file exists in your filesystem. Then, you can reproduce the next step (send_file) and check the error log.

I'd then advise you to open the source code of CarrierWave gem in your computer and find what's wrong with your code.

In your terminal, go to your project directory and run:

```
bundle show carrierwave
```

This will print you the path of the carrierwave gem's source you are using. Open it in your editor and find what's wrong with your code, according to the error log!

**Tip**

If you provide the current error log (after your update), we may help you better.

```
Cannot read file #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f570c2b9e58>
```

is not enough. The full backtrace would be better than this "one line" of code (use pastebin whenever possible).